# Pandas Split by delimiter when last delimiter may not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I am building out an ETL process in Python with the help of Pandas. I am trying to split some of the flat files by the delimiter "`_`" in which, within the column I want to split, there are some rows that contain 3 delimiters and some that contain 4 delimiters (as an additional details part).

In the example a file that contains 3 delimiters within the column, if I add column 5 and use n=4, it gives me a `Columns must be same length as key` error which makes sense as there are only 3 delimiters (if i use only 4 columns and n=3 it works but not what I want).

How can I get around this and when it spots the extra delimiter still splits it into a column and if not just leaves that column as null or blank. I also want to specify a n value as I do not want it to keep splitting at every delimiter. Any help would be amazing!

```
df[['column1','column2','column3','column4',
'column5 may or may not exisit']] = df['Column_to_split'].str.split('_',n=4,expand=True)
```

Example Data

```
0  Column_to_split  nextcolumn   nextcolumn   nextcolumn   nextcolumn
0  text_text_text   text2        text3        text4        23
1  text_text_text   text2        text3        text4        8
```

Desired Result

```
0  Column_to_split  Column_to_split1  Column_to_split2  Column_to_split3  Column_to_split4  nextcolumn   nextcolumn   nextcolumn   nextcolumn
0  text_text_text   text              text              text              null              text2        text3        text4        23
1  text_text_text   text              text              text              null              text2        text3        text4        8
```

Comment: itertuples or iterrows? You said it varies each row in a single DataFrame?

Comment: Sorry not sure how that would help? Yes it varies within each row of the dataframe so sometimes there may be 3 delimiters and sometimes there maybe 4, however, some files have only 3 and some have only 4.

Comment: Can you just change how you read in the data frame in the first place? Can you specify the column names at `read_csv`? Also, can you provide a little sample data?

Comment: Can't really provide specific column names as I want it to be slightly dynamic

Comment: @user2407147 did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something; does this approach work for you?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["text1, text2, text3, text4", "text1, text2, text3, text4, text5"], columns=["column_name"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                         column_name
0         text1, text2, text3, text4
1  text1, text2, text3, text4, text5
```

Split the single column into many columns:

```
df_split = df["column_name"].str.split(",", expand=True)
print(df_split)
```

Output:

```
       0       1       2       3       4
0  text1   text2   text3   text4    None
1  text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
```

You can rename the columns after this operation.

```
df_split.rename(columns={0:"column1"}, inplace=True)
print(df_split)
```

Output:

```
  column1       1       2       3       4
0   text1   text2   text3   text4    None
1   text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
```

Alt approach, after your comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["text1, text2, text3, text4",
                   "text1, text2, text3, text4, text5"], 
                   ["text1, text2, text3, text4",
                   "text1, text2, text3, text4, text5"]],
                   columns=["column1", "column2"])
print(df)

list_of_dfs = []

for col in df.columns:
    temp_df = df[col].str.split(",", expand=True)
    print(temp_df)
    list_of_dfs.append(temp_df)

split_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
print(split_df)
```

Sample output:

```
       0       1       2       3
0  text1   text2   text3   text4
1  text1   text2   text3   text4
       0       1       2       3       4
0  text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
1  text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
       0       1       2       3       4
0  text1   text2   text3   text4     NaN
1  text1   text2   text3   text4     NaN
0  text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
1  text1   text2   text3   text4   text5
```

Comment: Hey thanks for offering this however I have more than one column in my whole dataset. This just filters down to that one column and then break that out

Comment: I get this error "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Comment: Can you post the code (in your original question) that generates that error? TIA.